# How to display date in rows, when date selected from Date Picker?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

When I select date from **Date picker**

[image]

It should in display in Days like `Rows` as shown below.

For ex: If I select today date in Date Picker. In 2017 December month there are 31 days, so it should display 1 to 31st with Days Sun, Mon, Tue,...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datapicker has onSelect function, so you could bind your custom logic in the function.

[Original thread](http://www.phpknowledgebase.com/how-to-call-a-function-onselect-event-of-datepicker-in-jquery/)

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
numberOfMonths: 1,
onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
update(selected);
}
});

function update(value){
alert('this is your value'+value);
//to do, custom logic, you may use jQuery to add element/CSS to data view dynamically.
}
```